# script (.bat) to add REG_SZ with a data value in this path

Tags: script, windows-registry

I am looking for a script (.bat)  to add REG_SZ with a data value in this path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default
```

please advise

Answer (score 1):

Use `REG` command

```
@echo off

REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /ve /f /d "string data"
```

To activate registry changes in HKEY_CURRENT_USER without logging off, you may want to add following command:

```
RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters,1,True
```

You can read more about using `reg` [here](https://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

Comment: REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /t REG_SZ /d "test" /f

If you want to update the actual "(Default)".

Comment: @EMK "default" value should be set with `/ve` and `/t REG_SZ` is set by default in `reg`.

Comment: Are you sure those spaces are in the right place in the `rundll32.exe` command line? They look wrong to me...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling You absolutely right, result of copy/pasting :( Fixed, thanks for the help to improve it